# MSSQL: Table Partitioning Key

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Given the following table structure, which would be the best key candidate for partition key? I've got 500million records and have partitioned by month using the eventDate which is static, however, the lastUpdated could be updated up to a week later, if not up to x number of weeks post eventDate.

Could lastUpdated also be a good candidate or not? and why.

[image]

The table has x5 non-clustered indexes on **lastUpdated** and **no keys** exist referencing **eventDate**

- key 1 (id)
- key 2 (lastUpdated)
- key 3 (id, lastUpdated)
- key 4 (recipient,lastUpdated)
- key 5 (delivery, lastUpdated)

**Current issue:**

1. The current table is being constantly queryed for marketing segmentation, so a single select could fetch hundreds of thousands if not millions and multiple processes could be also running multiple selects on the same table with different criteria
2. During high traffic days, there could be millions of rows of data to be inserted and/or updated; all this whilst step 1 is also taking place.

**Current performance:** The inserts/updates and selects to this table is very slow. I thought by introducing table partitioning could enhance performance in some way.

Comment: Partitioning isn't really a performance related feature. It's a data management feature. I'd recommend posting details about some of your most expensive queries so that you can look at those to improve performance

Comment: For performance questions, Brent's [article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) offers good tips how to gather supporting evidence. Some typical queries with actual execution plans would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, appreciate it, could you still let me know which column would be the best candidate?

Comment: "*could you still let me know which column would be the best candidate?*" - No. It's an impossible question to answer based on what you've provided so far. Please listen to the previous comments suggestions. Please upload your slow queries' actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link them in your Post. Almost certainly Partitioning is not the feature you're looking for. It looks like your indexes can probably be tuned, for example `(id, lastUpdated)` seems unnecessary if `id` is a unique field. You also don't mention your clustered index?

Comment: I'm sure there are many other things that can be improved on to help your performance problems that will be evident in your execution plans.

Comment: Hi J.D thanks, will any columns tied to id be wortheless? I have another index (id, deliveryid) deliveryid is foreign key, so not unique on this table. there is no cluster index on this table.

Comment: Using a column that is frequently updated is generally a bad idea, as it might cause row migration between partitions.

Comment: "*there is no cluster index on this table.*" - That's probably part of your performance problems. *Almost* all tables should have a clustered index. Without one your Table is stored in a Heap structure & probably suffers from fragmentation problems which would affect performance for `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `SELECT` statements. If you made `id` your clustered index, given that it's unique, then any query that filters on `= id` would only need a single index on just `(id)`, since it's a single row exact match equality search. If you do range searches on `id` (e.g. `>= id`) then different story.